# Get Sequence of Range Numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, math

I have a sequence of numbers like this and I want to create a function to calculate it to get the result like. I can archive it when my input number is higher than or equal to 15, but when the number is lower than 15 it has some problem.

```
11=0
12=1
13=2
14=3

15=0
16=1
17=2
18=3

19=0
20=1
21=2
22=3

23=0
24=1
25=2
26=3

27=0
28=1
...
...
...
```

I've tried

```
public getResult(a: number): number {
    const calc = (a - 15);
    if (calc < 0) {
       return 4- Math.abs(calc) % 4;
    }
    return calc % 4;
 }
```

Comment: Seems to be as simple as calculating `(a + 1) % 4`

Comment: The problem statement is not clear to me . Not sure what you want to calculate `I want to create a function to calculate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer

```
public getResult(a: number): number {
   return ((a % 4) + 1) % 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
getResult(a) {
    if(a < 11) {
        return null ;
    }

    return ((a - 11) % 3) ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but when `a =  10` it will return null. I want a to be any number and it returns the correct result

Comment: Your example starts from `11`. If it should start from other value (say `5`), replace in the solution the `11` by the starting value (i.e. `5`). And if it solves your problem, I'd appreciate you mark the answer as correct (click on the "V" at the left).